# restore current sections for next test case in Selenium scripts

Tags: selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I am using selwnium web driver. When I am using selenium and nunit to run my test cases I find that every time a test case starts it open a new page and when its done the mew page will be destoryed. Therefore I have to open new page and login in every test case.

I want to have my test cases share one single webpage so that they can be performed in sequence.

Is a selenium limitation, or is it a way to implement it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare `Webdriver` instance variable as `static` inside your `test class` and initialize only once. Your behavior is because different webdriver instances does not share the same `session`, so therefore you have always to login into desired page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably using `@Before , @After` annotation.
Try use `@BeforeClass, @AfterClass`  instead. e.g:

```
....
static WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {


        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }
.....
```